# INNER JOIN - Result of select more then one row error

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

It may a noobish question but by Googling I think I have to use inner join, but could not get it work:

I would like to run an SQL command to get data from table A if it exists in table B and all expected columns are matching, but I get "Result of select more then one row" error on AS400 of course, 'cause I need it all.

What am I doing wrong? Goal is to use table B as WHERE condition while selecting from table A.

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4, column5
from TableA INNER JOIN
     TableB
     ON TableA.column1 = TableB.column1 and
        TableA.column2 = TableB.column2 and 
        TableA.column3 = TableB.column3
```

TableA and TableB is also having many rows.

Thank you!

Comment: Just to note, it might be a problem: values are not unique, TableA has many rows matching with TableB's column values.

Comment: Put some sample data with your expected output from them.

Answer (score 2):

Your error does not make sense with that query.  However, if you just want columns from one table, use `exists`:

```
select a.*
from TableA a
where exists (select 1
              from TableB b
              where a.column1 = b.column1 and
                    a.column2 = b.column2 and 
                    a.column3 = b.column3
             );
```

This prevents the `JOIN` from introducing duplicates -- and often has better performance.